# Arguments with space when parsing input parameters for bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal, ubuntu-16.04

I wrote a bash script which takes parameters by name and read its value in key value pairs. Below is an example of how I run my script.

```
 sh test.sh param1='a' param2='b'
```

I then refer the input arguments like $param1 and $param2 inside my script. Below is the script I wrote to do this.

```
for item in $@; do
case $item in
(*=*) eval $item;;
esac
done
```

But when there is space in the value of the argument, it takes only the part before the space.

```
 param3='select * from'
```

would only assign 'select' to param3 and not the whole string. How can I achieve this? Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT :

After Inian's answer

```
for item in $@; do
case "$item" in
(*=*) eval "$item";;
esac
done
```

Comment: Have you considered passing them in as variables instead, i.e. `param1='a' param2='b' sh test.sh` instead? This will make `echo "$param1"` available immediately without parsing

Comment: Using $@ or $* without enclosing in double quotes is not a good idea.  It would misbehave when your strings have special characters in them, like whitespace and wildcards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by quoting `"$@"` and using `declare` instead of `eval`:

```
for item in "$@"; do
case $item in
(*=*) declare "$item" ;;
esac
done
```

However, this is now a bash script, so you have to run it with `bash test.sh` and not `sh test.sh`

Comment: That did the trick! but as you have indicated in the comment, what is the difference between specifying parameters after "sh <scriptName>" and before "sh <scriptName"> ? sorry I am new to this.

Comment: @mayooran: if you specify them before the command, they're interpreted as environment variable assignments *by the calling shell*, so they're directly available in the script. If you put them after, they're interpreted as strings to pass to the script as `$1`, `$2`, etc, and then you have to do something nonstandard and weird to turn them into variable assignments. The normal way for scripts to take arguments is either as bare strings in a standard order (e.g. `sh test.sh val1 val2`), or use `-` options to specify them (e.g. `sh test.st -a val1 -b val2`).

Comment: @GordonDavisson oh, got it mate! thanks a lot! :) :)